# GCM push noti in Unity3d causes gms.iid.InstanceID classnotfound

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, google-play-services

I have made an Android plugin to use GCM in my Unity app. When I try to start the RegistrationIntentService (readymade example class from Android Developer Manual site), it causes a crash with the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ex.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ex.test-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have imported the play-services-9.2.0.unitypackage, without any success. Any help?

Comment: from where did you get that plugin (unity package) ?

Comment: @JeanLuc from the officlial github diretory

Comment: link or it didn't happen.

Comment: @JeanLuc I don't understand what you mean but this is the GitHub repository URL https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might want to look for this question answered, I found the solution. The InstanceID.class is not included in the play-services-9.2.0.unitypackage, so include the play-services-iid-9.0.2.aar in the Android -> Plugins folder.